# IllegalArgumentException when using h:selectOneRadioButton in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have following facelet code for JSF 1.2 application xhtml file :

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{cdM.val}"> 
       <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.myBooleanValues}" />      
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

The userBean.myBooleanValues method returns select Item as : new SelectItem(Boolean.TRUE, "Yes") and similar for "NO"

cdM.val is having type as : Object val;

I am getting below exception when above radio component is rendered on UI .
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Value is no String (class=java.lang.Boolean, value=true) and component form0: with path: .......does not have a Converter.

The most strange part is that , above exception disappears when jsf facelet jar version is : jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar. (and appears for jsf-facelets-1.1.11.jar).

Do I need to write any convertor to deel with the exception

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search I resolved below issue like this  :

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{cdM.val} converter="javax.faces.Boolean"> 
       <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.myBooleanValues}" />      
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

where cdM.val contains values : "Yes" or "No".
The convertor is used to convert values between String (cdM.val) and Boolean (userBean.myBooleanValues).

The exception got resolved.